# Sending notifications in the channel bot

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm currently in the approval process of getting my app approved into the store. One of the remaining issues is:

`1. Employer and Employee both didn’t receive any notification in the channel bot`

My bot is currently set to `notificationOnly` in the manifest.json as I don't need/want users to message it directly.

Looking through the "Proactive Messaging" documentation, it's a little vague as to what messages and when to send them would pass the above failure.

Do I need to send the message to channel?

I'm currently using NodeJS

Thanks

Comment: What exception are you getting? Could you please share some code snippet?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I'm not getting an exception, my question is what and when should be sent to fulfill the feedback from the approval team? What notifications need to be sent to the "Employer" (the person adding the app) and the "Employee" (members of the team). The bot is "notificationOnly" as i dont want users sending messages to it. I just need to know what i need to do to satisfy the reason why my app wasn't approved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a long answer that covers many areas, simply because I'm not 100% sure I know what kind of notification you aren't receiving. Please add additional detail to your question if this doesn't answer it and I will edit this answer.

#### Troubleshooting

- [Troubleshooting Guide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/troubleshoot-notifications-for-teams-mobile-apps-6d125ac2-e440-4fab-8e4c-2227a52d460c#ID0EAABAAA=Android)

  - Pay special attention to the *many* areas where notifications need to be enabled

    - **In particular, the user may need to "Follow" and/or "Favorite" the channel to receive notifications from it**
- If a user has the desktop app open, they will receive the notification there and will not receive one on their phone unless they have been inactive on the desktop app for 3+ minutes. Otherwise, it's likely a bug in Teams.

#### Chat Notifications

If you've followed the Troubleshooting Guide linked above, your users should receive chat notifications. If not, you can try updating your MS Teams desktop or mobile client. It may also be helpful to `@` mention users and/or channels

#### Sending an Activity With a Normal Notification

Often, the key issue needing to add the `trustServiceUrl` code from below. Normally, neglecting to do this manifests itself with a 500 error, but for Teams, it appears to not create notifications. You basically need to set a couple of properties of turncontext.activity and trusting the serviceUrl.

Instantiate some key variables:

```
const teamsChannel = '19:8d60061c3d10xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@thread.skype';
const serviceUrl = 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/';
```

- Note: the easiest way to get these variables is to send a message from Teams to the bot while putting a breakpoint on the incoming activity
- serviceUrl likely varies by geo region

Send the activity

```
// This ensures that your bot can send to Teams - serviceUrl ensures notifications, too
turnContext.activity.conversation.id = teamsChannel;
turnContext.activity.serviceUrl = serviceUrl;
MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);

await turnContext.sendActivity(yourActivity);
```

#### Activity Feed Notifications

You can also [create Activity Feed Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/activity-feed). The gist of it is that you need to:

1. Include `text` and `summary` in the message
2. Include `channelData` that sets `notifications.alert` to true

This code will accomplish that:

```
const msg = MessageFactory.text('my message');
msg.summary = 'my summary';
msg.channelData = {
    notification: {
        alert: true,
    },
};
return await dc.context.sendActivity(msg);
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

*Note: To receive notifications, you and your users **must** follow the channel.*